# Why aren't my Bootstrap grid properties behaving responsively in VS Code?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

grid properties of bootstrap in vs code not working prperly

This code should make the columns behave responsively but it is not showing
when i use .col-lg-6 is shows response. it is showing responsiveness for lg, xl, xxl but not for md and sm why is it so ??
I am using VS code IDE

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: yellow;">
            Hello
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: hotpink ;">
            hello
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```